# SVN repository on Google Drive - synchronisation doesn't work properly

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, google-drive-api

I want my code to be synced between my computers, so I just set up SVN repository on Google Drive. Okay, I commit changes, make sure Google Drive has synced my data well, turn off the first computer. Now, when I want to update on second computer it just doesn't find any newer revisions (I tried pressing "SVN Update" a few times), but when I turn on the first computer and do update on second it updates well (in this time I look at Google Drive and it doesn't show the update icon on my repository directory).

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: So actually turns out Google Drive has a delay of about 10 minutes before the new files appear...

Answer (score 1):

Google drive is definitely not the best option for hosting svn repository. Did you evaluate any hosted solution? If you have an open source project you can get a repository for free. For example take a look at svn hosting comparison matrix at [svnrating.com](http://svnrating.com/)